# Building a mysql query from 6 tables to reduce php usage

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

First, I don't know if this is the right exchange. I've been working on a system for requesting feedback in a score from 1 to 5 to people around you, but I'm having trouble building the query for displaying the result. Another dev has already made the tables, so I have to work with this. I have this mysql-database.

These are the simplified tables, so you get the idea. These are static:

```
users
user_id || user_name || user_email

questions
question_id || theme_id || question

themes
theme_id || theme_title
```

And these are the ones where the users can add records. A user selects a theme and sends requests to other users.

```
sentlists
list_id || created_by_user_id || theme_id

requests
request_id || to_user_id || sent_list_id || answered

responses
response_id || request_id || rating
```

How can I build a query (if at all possible) that, when given a list_id, results in a result like this:

```
user_name || question name 1 || question name 2 || question name 3 || question name 4
Michael || 2 || 3 || 1 || 4
```

I've been breaking my head over this for the past couple hours, and I can't come up with a good solution. I could fall back to PHP, but that would result in multiple queries for one result.

Comment: How are users linked to questions? There isn't an obvious primary/foreign key relationship based on what you've laid out here. Also, are you wanting a set of columns, one for each question a user has submitted? If so, you're probably better off requesting one row per question per user. Otherwise, what happens when one user has 2 questions and another has 3?

Comment: Can you show some sample data?  I'm not following what a *theme* is or how it relates to a *question*.

Comment: I am guessing theme is the term used for "questionnaire", "test", "survey". Also, guessing desired results is column names = questions and column contents containing that users answers?

Comment: @Uueerdo is right. Users are not allowed to submit their own questions, they have to choose from _themes_, make their own record in sentlists and are able to send requests to other users. I will adjust the question.

Comment: All that said, I think the question is asking for a "Cross Tab" query; one of the harder to do things in MySQL, with solutions that end up being convoluted, inflexible, and high-maintenance.

Comment: Of course, a solution is a lot easier using PHP (as I can request all the responses per answered request individually), but is also a lot more resource expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my cross tab assumption is correct, you are better off assembling the final results in code. In which case, it is probably unlikely you'll need multiple queries; the obvious `JOIN`s with a helpful `ORDER BY` (such as `ORDER BY user_name, question_name, answer`) should make the code portion relatively simple.

*You cannot vary result fields in a single query. You can use code to create queries dynamically, but that often ends up more work than it is worth.*

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question.

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from sentilists as a 
join users as b on a.created_by_user_id = b.user_id
join questions as c on a.theme_id = c.theme_id ..... and so on
```

I am not sure how theme and questions are related so maybe you can clarify that but I guess a multijoin would work in your situation.

Comment: I know how to build a join-query, but the point is that the amount of collums can change depending on the theme associated with the list (and corresponding request)